# Python sklearn classification: customize objective score function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

How to customize the score function in sklearn package?

For example, in the binary classification problem, instead of setting score as "percentage of all correctly predicted labels", set it as "percentage of all correctly predicted positive labels (label == 1)"

Comment: Please provide more information - it's hard to answer with so little to go on.  Which classification algorithm are you using?  Is your problem just calculating that metric after running your training/testing, or are you trying to impact how your algorithm trains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe as "percentage of all correctly predicted positive labels" is a very known metric called **precision**. It is implemented in SKlearn.metrics [[LINK]](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html#sklearn.metrics.precision_score).

The most common metric used for classification is **accuracy** and is what you described as "percentage of all correctly predicted labels". Also implemented in SKlearn.metrics [[LINK]](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html#sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score).

I recommend you also take a look at SKlearn's User Guide, Section **Model Evaluation** [[LINK]](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#defining-your-scoring-strategy-from-metric-functions).